# How to get a generic component property that has been passed into my canDeactivate Guard in Angular?

Tags: angular, casting, typescript-generics, angular-guards

I want to pass multiple components (Component1 | Component2) into my canDeactivate guard, so I'm using generics like this below.

**Problem** - There is a property I want to access from each of the components I pass in, so how do get the generic components property?

Do I have to cast or something?
I can see in the debugger that the component is there, but I can't access the properties until I'm inside the function live.

FYI - `component.profileForm.dirty` doesn't work because it doesn't know what T is until I'm inside the function

```js
export class PreventUnsavedChangesGuard <T> implements CanDeactivate <T> {

  constructor(private confirmService: ConfirmService) {}

  canDeactivate(component: T): Observable < boolean > | boolean {
    if (component.hasOwnProperty('profileForm')) {
      if (component.profileForm.dirty) {
        return this.confirmService.confirm();
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an interface containing the minimal information you expect your component to have, e.g.,

```
interface HasProfileForm {
    profileForm: Form
}
```

and then you could modify your guard to be use the new interface, e.g.,

```
export class PreventUnsavedChangesGuard <T extends HasProfileForm> implements CanDeactivate <T> {

  constructor(private confirmService: ConfirmService) {}

  canDeactivate(component: T): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    if (component.hasOwnProperty('profileForm')) {
      if (component.profileForm.dirty) {
        return this.confirmService.confirm();
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jacopo. I figured out I get the property by doing this: if (component['profileForm'].dirty), would your solution be better or worse than what I did?

Comment: I think it would be better because you would enforce that requirement through a type, which somehow the big thing behind Typescript.